# When can a cross product of two vectors be substituded for the product of their lengths?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I am working my way through an exercise on non-inertial reference frames, in which a mass point is moving onto a piece of spinning wire. In the process of simplifying the motion equation, the book shows the following calculation:

$m\ddot x \vec{e_1}=\vec{F_{Wire}}-m\vec{\omega} \times(\vec{\omega}\times x \vec{e_1})-2m\vec{\omega}\times(\dot x \vec{e_1})=\vec{F_{Wire}} + m \omega^2x\vec{e_1}-2m\omega\dot x \vec{e_2}$.

I don't understand how the vectors are being replaced by their lengths here. If anything, in the second term, the cross product of the angular velocity with itself should give 0 as a result. In the last term, I understand that getting $\vec{e_2}$ makes sense, as it is orthogonal to the two vectors of the cross product, but I, again, do not see how the length of the angular velocity vector comes to be.

Would appreciate your input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $x'$..?

Comment: The second term has parentheses for a reason, note that $\omega \times e_1$ is perpendicular to the direction of $\omega$ and $e_1$.

Comment: It was supposed to be x. I have removed the ' which is used to differentiate the coordinates in the non-inertial reference frame, as my question only concerns this frame of reference.

Comment: Fair enough, I see why the second term wouldn't give the zero vector. Could you direct me further on which rule was applied to get the length of the vectors?

Comment: I am fairly certain this calculation only works with an assumption on the direction of $\omega$ relative to the $e_i$, in particular $\omega$, $e_1$ and $e_2$ need to be (pairwise) orthogonal otherwise there would be additional terms. Maybe check the text of your book for info/assumptions on the directions...? ;)

Comment: That's exactly what it was, thanks a lot!